# Collection Bag wtih annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm watching a good video made by **Burt Beckwith**

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance

he says:

> "In traditional Hibernate you could map the collection as Bag,
>
> which is just a regular Collection with no ordering or uniqueness guarantees"

How Can I map this collection with no ordering or uniqueness with annotation? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use a `List` as the reference type but do not specify an index number column, you will have an unordered collection with no uniqueness requirement.  Yes the list is an ordered collection at the java level, but there is no guarantee across copies of the entity that they have the same order.

```
@OneToMany
private List<OtherEntity> otherEntities;
```

That's all!

Comment: Please explain what is: "do not specify an index number column"? what do you mean

Comment: @J.J.Beam  To specify an index number column would be to use the hibernate IndexColumn annotation (or its successor the JPA2 OrderColumn annotation.)

Comment: hmm so when write: 
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Student> students;  is this a bag??? LOL I used Bag everytime and didnt realized it )))

Comment: @J.J.Beam 7 years ago in Hibernate 3.3 it was.  If you're asking about how Hibernate 5/6 work I suggest asking a new question, I don't use those technologies anymore and honestly don't consider myself an expert in the latest versions.

Comment: Use @OrderColumn instead of IndexColumn as IndexColumn is deprecated in hibernate 5/6.