# Hibernate Collection Performance Issues

Tags: java, hibernate

In the video made by **Burt Beckwith**

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance

Burt point some interesting behaviours with Collection on hibernate

First with Set

> " Adding to the Set requires loading all instances from the database
>
> to guarantee uniqueness, even if you know the new item is unique "

And List

> " Likewise for a mapped List = Hibernate pulls the entire collection
>
> to maintain the correct order, even if you're adding to the end of the list "

He shows how to solve it

> " In traditional Hibernate you could map the collection as Bag, witch is just
>
> a regular Collection with no ordering or uniqueness guarantees "

As I'm using annotation on my project, I asked here how to create a Collection with no

ordering or uniqueness:

[Collection Bag wtih annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527450/collection-bag-wtih-annotation)

this is the annotation mapping:

```
@ManyToOne
private List<OtherEntity> otherEntities;
```

This mapping is going to prevent hibernate of loading all instances from database when I

add an element to the List? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question: You're asking us to confirm what Affe already said?

Comment: No. I want hibernate to avoid loading when adding elements (behaviour described above). To achieve that I should map the collection as a Bag right ? But there is no such a thing as bag with jpa/anottation. Affe showed me how to map something similar to a bag. My question: Is that going to avoid hibernate of loading entire lists before insert, like bag does?